# C# usar un DSN para conectar a MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

como va?
Hace poco estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta a programar desde 0, siguiendo tutoriales, leyendo foros, etc.

Hasta ahora cada vez que quiero realizar, por ejemplo desde una aplicacion de Windows Forms, alguna operación para agregar, leer o modificar registros en una base de datos de MYSQL, estoy usando una clase de conexión especificada en el código de la siguiente manera:

```
     class DBConexion
{
    public MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; database=base1;port=3306;UID=root;password=root;sslmode=none");

    public void Abrir()
    {
        conexion.Open();
    }

    public void Cerrar()
    {
        conexion.Close();
    }

}
```

Luego por ejemplo, si quiero consultar en la base de datos al clickear un button de un form, entonces hago:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBConexion cc = new DBConexion();
        cc.Abrir();

        string cadena = "select nombre from clientes where numero = 1";

        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(cadena,cc.conexion);
        MySqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();

        if(registro.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = registro["nombre"].ToString();
        }

        cc.Cerrar();
    }
```

Hasta ahora, de lo que llevo aprendiendo, es la mejor manera a la que llegué para realizar operaciones con la base de datos en MYSQL. Pero resulta que si yo quisiera cambiar los datos de conexión debería modificarlos directamente desde el código en la clase, lo cual claramente no sería práctico.

Yo trabajo en una empresa donde el sistema que usamos para la gestión interna utiliza una conexión ODBC configurada desde windows a la base de datos, y a través de un archivo .ini donde especifica el nombre del DSN que tiene que utilizar usa esa conexión, previamente configurado en windows desde Herramientas > Adminitratiivas > Origenes de Datos ODBC.

Me gustaría poder hacer esto mismo, pero hace días estoy buscando y no he podido encontrar información que explique bien todos los pasos o que debo usar para poder realizarlo de esta manera. Si alguien me puede guiar o pasar algún link para poder avanzar con esto,les agradecería mucho!!

Comment: Suena sencillo, supongo ese archivo .ini siempre está en la misma ruta en todas las máquinas, por lo que podrías leerlo y obtener el nombre del DSN, para cadenas de conexión de cualquier tipo te recomiendo esta página. https://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn/, y usarias todos esos objetos pero en vez de MySql existen los de ODBC, por ejemplo OdbcConnection

Comment: Asi es, siempre está en la misma ubicación el ini.

Quizás me faltó agregar que parte de lo que no pude entender de lo que encontré es como leer el archivo ini para que tome los valores configurados en la conexión configurada en el ODBC.

Si bien encontré bloques de código con ejemplos, no pude llegar a entender bien como era que funcionaban.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de tu ini y la ruta

Comment: el ini solamente dice:

DSN=conexion

Y hace referencia al DSN de sistema que se llama de la misma manera (conexion) que tiene los siguientes valores

Data Source Name: conexion
server: localhost
user: root
password: root
database: base1

Comment: Y la ubicacion es C:\Programa\Bases.ini en este caso (siempre se guarda donde esta instalado el programa)

Comment: Intenta leerlo así => string dsn = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Programa\Bases.ini"); y como te mencione al inicio debes usar los objetos pero con Odbc => OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(dsn);